# How are tennis mixed doubles seeds determined?

Tags: tennis, ranking

This is the [Mixed-double draw of Wimbledon 2017](http://www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/draws/index.html?event=MX).

How are the seeds determined in Mixed Double tournaments considering that there is no general rankings?

Comment: Sir what do you mean by no general ranking i'm not getting that, could you please explain.

Answer (score 1):

The [2017 Grand Slam Rule Book](http://www.itftennis.com/officiating/rulebooks/grand-slams.aspx) makes no difference between Men's, Women's or Mixed Doubles (see page 30). Therefore the same seeding system is used for all three.

The selection of seeds is based on the team ranking, which is calculated by adding the better of each player's singles or doubles ranking.

Ties are broken in the following way:

1. Teams using 2 singles rankings
2. Teams using 1 singles ranking
3. Teams using 2 doubles rankings

Comment: This seems to be consistent with the way doubles seeds are done in ATP and WTA tournaments: [How are doubles seeds calculated?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/10444) (Of course, there is no mixed competition there.)