# How are doubles tennis players matched?

Tags: rules, tennis, atp, wta, qualifying

I have a few questions regarding doubles players playing together on the mens', womens' and the mixed tournaments.

- How are the doubles tennis players partnered up? Is this totally based on players' decision?
- How do the doubles players qualify for tournaments, specially if they just begin playing together?
- Are there any requirements that the players need to respect in order to play together?
- Are the rules the same for the mixed and non mixed doubles players?

If different tournaments have different rules, then please at least list those of the grand slam's.

Comment: Related: [How are doubles seeds calculated?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/10444) For entry and seeding a kind of "combined" ranking of the two players is used.

Comment: This is at least three different questions and should be asked as such.

Comment: Asking these questions separately creates repetition, they're all related to each other. See this https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334/is-it-okay-to-ask-multiple-questions-of-the-same-topic-in-a-single-question